# Alternative formulation of the Law of Total Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Usually the following formulation of the Law of Total Probability is used:

> If events $\{H_i\}$ with positive probabilities form the partition of a sample space then for any event $A$ on the same probability space we have $P(A) = \sum_{i} P(A|H_i)P(H_i)$

Do we rigorously need the partition here? Can we use the following alternative formulation instead?

> If pairwise disjoint events $\{H_i\}$ with positive probabilities form the cover of the event $A$ (i.e. $A \subseteq \bigcup_i H_i$) then we have $P(A) = \sum_{i} P(A|H_i)P(H_i)$.

Comment: Your alternative formulation is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What is $\Pr ( A \vert H_i )$ when $A \cap H_i = \emptyset$?

This should tell you the connection between the two statements.

Comment: Yes, when $A \cap H_i = \varnothing$ then $P(A|H_i) = 0$.

Comment: @Rodvi Good. Now you should hopefully be able to see why the sum in your first statement is the same as the sum in the second.

Comment: I see. Just want to say that the second statement may be more convenient in situation when we don't know the partition of $\Omega$. In that case it will be enough to find the cover of $A$ to apply LOTP using the second statement.

Comment: @Rodvi To be honest I can’t imagine a situation where you might not know the partition, though that might be due to a lack of imagination on my part. However, the two statements _are_ equivalent, so you are free to use whichever you find more convenient.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have pairwise disjoint non-empty sets $\{ H_i \}$ that cover $A$, that *gives you* a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) --i.e., the class $\{ H_i \cap A \}$ partitions $A$.  So your second statement is not really an alternative result at all - it is just a way of stating the same result.

Comment: I disagree. Pairwise disjoint non-empty sets $\{H_i \}$ that cover $A$ give us **the partition of $A$**. While in the first formulation above $\{H_i\}$ form **the partition of sample space $\Omega$**. And $A \ne \Omega$.